# GRAILS - How to start using Twitter Bootstrap in Grails 3.2.9 and what's the best way to do it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, plugins, installation

What's the way to use Bootstrap in Grails 3.2.9? How to start? Should I use any plugins?

Answer (score 3):

To follow best practices use the [Grails Asset Pipeline](http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/). It may take a bit of practice to understand how the pipeline works but the general ideas are highlighted well in this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702532/grails-asset-pipeline-system-with-3rd-party-libs). The pipeline will create folders for your assets, (css, javascript, images for example) and you need to place your bootstrap files in the proper locations. Make sure you remember that [Bootstrap requires jQuery.](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

> Please note that **all JavaScript plugins require jQuery**...

So be sure to include jQuery in your javascript folder. The other concept to grasp is creating the manifest file. For javascript assets it might look similar to:

Example file path:

```
grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.js
```

Example file contents:

```
//This is a JavaScript file with its top level require directives
//= require jquery
//= require app/models.js
//= require_tree views
//= require_self
console.log("This is my javascript manifest");
```

Then in the view you would like to uses the assets in, include the bootstrap assets by declaring:

```
<head>
    <asset:stylesheet href="application.css"/> //This assumes the standard pipeline path
    <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
    <asset:link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
</head>
```

Hopefully that helps you get started with loading Bootstrap via the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [webjars](http://www.webjars.org/)

build.grade

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.5"
}
```

grails-app\stylesheets\application.css

```
*= require /webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap
```

grails-app\javascripts\application.js

```
//= require /webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min
```